# HttpContext.Session requiere metodo o propiedad no estático en MVC ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Quiero consumir una **Web API.NET CORE** que utiliza **JWT** para autenticar y autorizar usuarios, tengo planeado consumir la API  desde MVC ASP.NET CORE utilizando `HTTPClient` y para ello guardaré el token generado por la API en una **variable de sesión** en mi aplicacion MVC y luego para cada `request` enviare el token en el `header`.

en `startup.cs` en `ConfigureServices` escribí esta línea de codigo:

```
services.AddSession()
```

y en Configure:

```
app.UseSession
```

Este es el código que consume la API y guarda el token en la variable de sesión:

```
public async Task<string> ObtenerJWT(ConsumirLogin datos)
        {           
            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datos);
            var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(BaseUrl, new StringContent(content, Encoding.Default, "application/json"));

            if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error");
            }

            string stringJWT = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
            JWT jwt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JWT>(stringJWT);

            HttpContext.Session.SetString("token", jwt.Token);
            return jwt.Token;
        }
```

He colocado un punto de interrupción y si logro llegar a consumir la API, si obtengo el token pero en la penúltima linea de codigo, **`HttpContext.Session.SetString("token", jwt.Token)`** me marca el error:

> Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad
>   'HttpContext.Session' no estáticos.

pueden ayudarme y decirme cual es el error?

este es el startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSession();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddHttpClient<IRepositorio, Repositorio>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddMemoryCache();
        }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: Me está pasando lo mismo que a ti, la línea
<!-- language: c# --> HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", usuario); me está dando el error "Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad 'HttpContext.Session' no estáticos". ¿Lo conseguiste solucionar? En caso afirmativo, ¿cómo lo solucionaste? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te en cuenta que estás obteniendo el Token JWT de manera asíncrona (`await`), ya que tu método `ObtenerJWT()` es de tipo `async`.

Esto quiere decir que estás intentando almacenar en sesión el resultado de un método asíncrono. Prueba a recuperar el token con un método síncrono, y obtén los resultados de `PostAsync()` y `ReadAsStringAsync()` a través de su propiedad **`.Result`**.

El código quedaría así:

```
    public string ObtenerJWT(ConsumirLogin datos)
    {           
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datos);
        var httpResponse = _client.PostAsync(BaseUrl, 
              new StringContent(content, Encoding.Default, "application/json")).Result;

        if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }

        string stringJWT = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
        JWT jwt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JWT>(stringJWT);

        HttpContext.Session.SetString("token", jwt.Token);
        return jwt.Token;
    }
```

---

***Nota***: Te recomiendo leas el siguiente artículo, donde puedes ver todo lo referente a utilizar Json Web Tokens en Web APIs de ASP.NET Core:
[JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API de .NET Core](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/5/20/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-de-net-core)

Comment: Hola, te cuento que la aplicación de JWT en Web API lo saque de tu pagina y me funciona bien, aplique también el de nswag, asi que gracias en cuanto a la respuesta brindada, me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Indica entonces por favor, el archivo Startup.cs para ver en que punto del PipeLine tienes incluido el app.UseSession(); (El orden importa).

Comment: Y si puedes, el error completo y la pila. Aunque me extraña que te siga dando error con el método síncrono.

Comment: ok, he editado mi pregunta con el starup.cs

Comment: @PabloMayora Ese no, el Configure (pipeline), a ver donde tienes el app.UseSession();. Aunque no creo que sea eso...

Comment: entiendo, actualizo pregunta

Comment: @PabloMayora: nada, parece todo correcto. La verdad que es un error bastante raro. Tienes el volcado entero del error?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99667/discussion-between-rafael-acosta-and-pablo-mayora).

Comment: Y cual es tu respuesta de httpResponse  ? No creo que sea un objeto token  digo como saber si las credenciales enviadas son incorrectas